# How to upload image from an external link in wordpress and save that image in wordpress upload folder?

Tags: wordpress

```
$img = ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/2014/07/'.$proimg[7].'large'.$proimg[8];

file_put_contents($img,'');
```

[here is](http://www.cardkingdom.com/catalog/item/190764) external link where I upload image.

I have done every thing but image does not work even i open it browser and widow photo viewer.

May be there are some permission issue.
when I open image in broswer I get the error image can't be display it contain error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_upload_dir` to get upload folder path in WordPress.

You can also use `wp_handle_upload`. It handles PHP uploads in WordPress, sanitizes file names, check extensions for mime type, and move the file to the appropriate directory within the uploads directory.

### Reference

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload

Comment: I have done every thing but image does't work me even after it upload in upload folder I download it on my system image having error in open I want that I uploaded image work for me .When i open image in browser I error me can't display it has error.